# Javascript Chart that supports Knockout.js

Tags: charts, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've searched for client side javascript chart which supports KO.js but haven't been able to find one.

Has anyone have had any experience with charts that supports KO.js? Reason I'm after KO is that when user toggles the chart parameters, the chart should get rendered automatically for selected parameter.

Comment: Maybe you could build on the work that has been done intergrating knockout with kendo ui (http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/) and extend it to support their data visualization tools (http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/overview/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely won't find that anytime soon; Good charting solutions or libraries in general don't take a stance over which particular application framework to use. In the (segmented) world of JS, one has to write adapters all the time (the most famous one being framework X to JQueryUI widgets); The devs at squareup plugged EmberJs with d3 so I see no reason why one couldn't do the exact same with knockout.

http://corner.squareup.com/2012/04/building-analytics.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out Wijmo? It includes charts and several other widgets, all with KnockoutJS support:

http://wijmo.com/widgets/mvvm-support/

There's a sample on CodeProject that shows how to build a stock portfolio application using KnockoutJS and the Wijmo line chart widget:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424656/A-Stock-Portfolio-Application-Using-KnockoutJS